# IBM Watson Visual Recognition parameters method won't accept String implicitly

Tags: java, eclipse, api, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I created a program with windows builder to make a custom classifier using IBM Watson services and everything works fine but I have problems with the classification of an image using that classifier's ID from a text fie.

When I put the custom classifiers ID inside the code it works fine but when I am trying to take that ID from a TextField it won't work.

Here is the code inside the button's action event. The variable `String id` outputs exactly What is inside the `parameters` method but it replaces the id (cats_599303326) with the id that is in the TextField but when I put `id` as an argument in the `parameters` method, program won't run successfully.

On the other hand, if I comment everything and just output the `id` String, copy and paste it inside the `parameters` method, It worked fine.

Why it won't work when I pass the variable `id` through?

```
VisualRecognition service = new VisualRecognition(
        VisualRecognition.VERSION_DATE_2016_05_20
);
service.setEndPoint("https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api");
service.setApiKey("{api-key}");
File imagesStream = new File(textField.getText());
ClassifyOptions classifyOptions = null;
String id = String.format("\"{\\\"classifier_ids\\\": [\\\"%s\\\"]}\"", textField_1.getText());
System.out.println(id);

try {
    classifyOptions = new ClassifyOptions.Builder()
            .imagesFile(imagesStream)
            .imagesFilename("Image ")
            .parameters("{\"classifier_ids\": [\"cats_599303326\"]}") //inside the parameters method, the goal is to replace cats_599303326 with an id given from a textfield
            .build();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

    e1.printStackTrace();
}
ClassifiedImages result = service.classify(classifyOptions).execute();
System.out.println(result);
```

Error log when putting the variable `id` as an argument in the `parameters` method, and as I said before, if I just print the `id` String, copy it and paste it as an argument in the `parameters` method program will run successfully but it won't run if i put it as a variable:

```
Jan 10, 2018 6:07:55 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> POST https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?version=2016-05-20&api_key=aca4433597018de62edafdeebceb2bdc1482496a http/1.1 (-1-byte body)
Jan 10, 2018 6:08:06 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- 400 Bad Request https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?version=2016-05-20&api_key=aca4433597018de62edafdeebceb2bdc1482496a (10214ms, 167-byte body)
Jan 10, 2018 6:08:06 AM com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService processServiceCall
SEVERE: POST https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?version=2016-05-20&api_key=aca4433597018de62edafdeebceb2bdc1482496a, status: 400, error: {
    "images_processed": 0,
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "description": "Invalid form data 'parameters'",
        "error_id": "parameter_error"
    }
}
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.BadRequestException: {
    "images_processed": 0,
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "description": "Invalid form data 'parameters'",
        "error_id": "parameter_error"
    }
}
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.processServiceCall(WatsonService.java:408)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$1.execute(WatsonService.java:174)
    at visualRecognitionSecondTry.ClassifyInterface$3.actionPerformed(ClassifyInterface.java:129)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If stackoverflow guys ban me for life and then come to my house and murder me, i would totally understand!! Solution was so simple it's embarrassing i did't think of it. Basically the String I created had extra quotation marks. The solution is :

`String id = String.format("{\"classifier_ids\": [\"%s\"]}", textField_1.getText());`

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates the service was unable to parse your JSON parameters object. I suspect you are either missing the quotation marks or not submitting the classifier_ids as an array when taking the value from your textfield, but cannot tell without more code for how you do that.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What I did wrong was put extra quotation marks in my string. This is so embarrassing. Basically what I did was instead of making a String = "Hello world!", I did String = ""Hello world!"" .